# What is this PDE called and what is its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know its a linear, first order, ordinary

$$\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x}=\alpha u(x)v(x)$$

or if it was like this...

$$\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x}=\alpha u(x)v(x)+u(x)$$

I think I need to do it numerically in Mathematica...

Comment: Not a PDE, and has explicit solution. Also, it's not clear what your question is

Comment: @Bananach could you elaborate? what is its explicit solution? what makes it not a PDE?

Comment: @Chessybo it’s not a PDE of course because it only involves derivatives of a single real variable, compare to equations like $u_t=u_{xx}$ for a function $u(t,x)$ (where subscripts denote partial derivatives).

Comment: They are usual ODEs of separable kind :$$\frac{d u}{d x}=\alpha u(x)v(x)\quad\implies\quad u(x)=c\:\exp\left(\alpha\int v(x)dx\right)$$
$$\frac{d u}{d x}=\alpha u(x)v(x)+u(x)\quad\implies\quad u(x)=c\:\exp\left(x+\alpha\int v(x)dx\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, both of the equations are ODEs and not PDEs. $u(x)$ is a function of a single variable $x$ and therefore you wouldn't take partial derivatives.

The linear ordinary differential equation

$$\frac{du(x)}{dx}=\alpha u(x)v(x)\tag{1a}$$

can be rewritten as

$$\frac{1}{u(x)}du(x)=\alpha v(x)dx$$

which upon integrating both sides forms

$$\ln |u(x)|=\alpha\int v(x)dx+C$$

or

$$u(x)=\text{exp}\Big({\alpha\int v(x)dx+C}\Big)=C~\text{exp}\Big({\alpha\int v(x)dx}\Big)\tag{1b}$$

Next, for

$$\frac{du(x)}{dx}=\alpha u(x)v(x)+u(x)\tag{2a}$$

rewrite this equation as

$$\frac{1}{u(x)}du(x)=\big(\alpha v(x)+1\big)dx$$

which upon integrating both sides forms

$$\ln |u(x)|=\alpha\int v(x)dx+x+C$$

or

$$u(x)=\text{exp}\Big({\alpha\int v(x)dx+x+C}\Big)=C~\text{exp}\Big({\alpha\int v(x)dx}+x\Big)\tag{2b}$$